# Binary outcome prediction based on multivariate time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, classification, multivariate-analysis

everyone!

I have some monitoring dataset for 90 patients. It consists of about 10 parameters (continuous variables) that were recorded each 1 minute 3-4 days for every patient. I know the binary outcome for every patient at the end of monitoring.
Now, I would like to predict the outcome (0/1) based on that multivariate time series for each patient.
What would you recommend to accomplish this? I am interested in R implementation.

Comment: Be aware that the statistical aspect of your question is on-topic here, but the R implementation is not. Someone may address that in combination with the rest, or it may not be addressed. We have some online resources for R listed [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/795/7290).

Comment: At least I need to know the prediction method to use in this case. Thank you!